# Java library to read a Microsoft Media Server (MMS) stream

Tags: java, streaming

I would like to know if there is available any Java library to read a Microsoft Media Server ([MMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Media_Server)) stream.

Thanks,

Douglas

Comment: Have you managed to find suitable Java MMS library? Maybe you know any relatively fresh library? JavaMMS mentioned in the answer didn't have any update since 2002 ...

Comment: @Denisigo, no, I haven't been able to find a suitable library for MMS processing since I asked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A google search reveals:

- [JavaMMS](http://javamms.sourceforge.net/) with a one and only "0.5 - Initial release" back in 2002
- Velocity Reviewers' forum discusses [Java MMS libraries] back in 2004, which leads on to
- [sdp.ppona.com](http://sdp.ppona.com/) a tool for download mms streams, which has a story:
- [Microsoft have finally released its MMS protocol specification!](http://sdp.ppona.com/news2008.html), Feb 2008
- [[MS-MMSP]: Microsoft Media Server (MMS) Protocol Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc234711.aspx)

It looks like the time is ripe for someone to make a Java MMS library. ;-)

I've had good experience using the [mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/) to dump MMS streams. With a little fiddling around and finding the right command line options. [all-streaming-media.com](http://all-streaming-media.com/record-video-stream/record-streaming-video-windows-media-and-real-video.htm#MPlayer) suggests using:

> mplayer.exe -dumpstream mms://somehost.com/somedirectory/somefile.wmv

Use the -dumpfile option to name the dumped stream:

> mplayer -dumpstream -dumpfile somefile.wav mms://somehost.com/somedirectory/somefile.wmv