# Java library to read a Microsoft MMS stream

Tags: java, streaming, mms

Sorry for duplicate question, but maybe does anyone know any relatively fresh Java library for reading MMS stream?

JavaMMS library suggested here ([Java library to read a Microsoft Media Server (MMS) stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207854/java-library-to-read-a-microsoft-media-server-mms-stream)) didn't have any update since 2002 and seems like it is not working for me.